# Unable to print the variable passed from view to template

Tags: django, html, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to pass the variable ,I am obtaining from view to the template but it is showing in the preview of the web-browser(chrome) but not on actual screen.
Following is my view file:

```
analyzer=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 
data={}
with open('today_5th_oct_new.csv','r',newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
     data[row[0]]=float(row[1])

analyzer.lexicon.update(data)

def index(request):
   return render(request, "gui/index.html")
@csrf_exempt

def output(request):
    sentences = request.POST.get('name',None)
    senti = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentences)
    context_dict = {'sentiment': senti}
    return render(request,"gui/index.html", context = context_dict)
```

Following is my template-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
    <body>
            <form action>
                Enter Sentence:<input id = "name" type = "text" name = "EnterSentence" encoding = "utf-8"><br>
                <input onclick = "testfunction()" type = "button" value = "Submit" >
            </form>
            <div><strong>Score is {{ sentiment }}</strong></div>
</body>
<script>
var testfunction = () => {
var test = document.getElementById("name").value
console.log(test)

 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         url: 'output/',
         data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
               'name': test
                },
                success: function(response) {
                console.log("Succesful return firm ajax call");
                },
                error: function(result){
                console.log("Failure");
                }
         });

}
</script>
```

I am observing the desired output in preview but not on actual page.
How to resolve that ?

[image: Preview output]

Comment: context should return the index function itself then only available in the template
in ajax call, you should return HttpResponse as JSON then you can access it from the ajax success function

Comment: Could you elaborate the method

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the response via Ajax but you're not doing anything with it. Your `success` function needs to insert the content into the page somehow.

To be honest, I don't see why you use Ajax here at all; if you removed the JS code and just let your form do a POST directly it would work fine.

Comment: but won't it got inserted when I passed it through the view from the context_dict

Comment: Inserted where? Your view function returns it to the Ajax, as you can see in the Chrome tools, but your Ajax script doesn't do anything with it so it doesn't display.

Comment: It seems like you are confused about Ajax, which is why I say you should not use it. Remove the JS completely and change your form tag to `<form action='.' method='POST'>`.

Comment: okay , I am new to both web development and ajax ,so apologies for my ignorance but after removing ajax ,how to pass the input to my view for further processing.

Comment: I don't understand the question. That is what the form is doing.